# Riesz Basis Of Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

We know that $\{x_k\}$ is a Riesz basis for $~H~$ if and only if there are constants $~0 ≤ A ≤ B~$ such that for
all finite sequences $${α_k},A||x||^2\leq\sum_{k}\langle x,x_k \rangle^2\leq B||x||^2.$$
My question: " Is every orthonormal basis a Riesz basis? "

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_sequence for the correct definition.

Answer (score 0):

(You have not stated the definition of a Riesz basis correctly). For an orthonormal basis $(x_k)$ we have $\|\sum a_k x_k\| ^{2}=\sum |a_n|^{2}$. So $(x_k)$ is a Riesz basis with $A=B=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and your can verify that $A=B=1$ for an orthonormal basis.